# Convert handwritten note to text

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note, s-note

The Samsung S-note app has a handwriting recognition mode that will turn handwriting to text in more or less real time, but it slows down input enough for it to not be really practical to use when jotting notes in meetings.

Is it possible to convert previously-taken handwriting and turn it to text later in S-note?  If not, then what about one of the other apps that come with the Galaxy note such as aNote HD?